# Angular 2 - Create user in a group AWS cognito

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am signing up a user into userpool(AWS Congito). How can I create user assigned to a group. I used following code for creating user, I wanna create and assign that to a group.

```
    this.userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoUserPool(this.poolData);
    this.attribute = {
        Name: 'email',
        Value: this.email
    };

    this.attributeEmail = new AWSCognito.CognitoUserAttribute(this.attribute);
    this.attributeList = [];
    this.attributeList.push(this.attributeEmail);

    this.userPool.signUp(this.username, this.password, this.attributeList, null, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
    });
```

I imported AWS and connected to Cognito Admin SDK. Called user creation method:

Updated code

```
  AWS.config.region = '<region>;
  AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: '<identity_poll_id>'
  });
  this.params = {
      UserPoolId: '<user_poll_id>',
      /* required */
      Username: this.username,
      /* required */
      DesiredDeliveryMediums: [
          'SMS'
      ],
      ForceAliasCreation: true,
      MessageAction: 'RESEND',
      TemporaryPassword: this.password,
      UserAttributes: [{
              Name: 'email',
              /* required */
              Value: this.email
          },
          /* more items */
      ],
      ValidationData: [{
              Name: 'email',
              /* required */
              Value: this.email
          },
          /* more items */
      ]
  };
  this.cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
  this.cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminCreateUser(this.params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      } else {
          console.log(data); // successful response
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Cognito Admin SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html) methods to create the user and add to the groups.

- To Create the User use [adminCreateUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminCreateUser-property) method with relevant parameters.
- To add the user to a group use, [adminUserAddToGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminAddUserToGroup-property) method.

Comment: Thanks alot for your valuable answer. I updated question and my code.  Response coming as "{"__type":"AccessDeniedException","Message":"User: arn:aws:sts::<no>:assumed-role/unauthenticated_user/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:AdminCreateUser on resource"

Comment: Where do you run this code, EC2 instance or Lambda or Locally? If its first two check the IAM role attached to them, whether it contains necessary permissions in policies. If its Locally, check the Users policies.

Comment: Running in local. Please suggest which policy need to attach for an IAM role.